# ASP.NET Core and Bootstrap : how to put dropdown inside form group?

Tags: forms, razor, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc, html-select

I'm using `<label asp-for` and `<input asp-for` tags inside my form to carry out "Create Form" action as well as Bootstrap for looks. How do I fix this bug, it's working with `asp-for`, I can create and edit successfully through these fields but its looks rather twisted than user friendly.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="City" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <label asp-for="Department" class="dropdown-item">HR</label>
                <input asp-for="Department" class="form-control" />
                <label asp-for="Department" class="dropdown-item">Sales</label>
                <input asp-for="Department" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="Department" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is the result:

Before select

[image]

During select

[image]

After select

[image]

As you can see its not populating inside the text field but its there, I tested it. Maybe there is other way to do it with HTML tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want something like this, you can use the `<select>` tag to implement the dropdown:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="City" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Department" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Department" class="form-control">
        <option selected>Choose Department</option>
        <option value="HR">HR</option>
        <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was looking for, Thank you Sir!